# How to query contentversion to Email Message

Tags: rest-api, contentversion, contentdocument, emailmessage, contentdocumentlink

We have integrated Salesfroce and our Support Page, and I have to send emailmessage via rest api along with attachment lies within the email, but I don't find a relateionship between Contentversion and the emailmessage.

I there a way to query contendocumentlink contendocument and contentvesion all in one??

Answer (score 1):

So, whenever you Insert ContentVersion, a link for ContentDocument is created, You can query that out.

One you have ContentDocumentId you can create a content document link and attach it to concerned EmailMessage

```
ContentVersion cv = [Select Id, ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion where Id='YOUR_INSERTED_CONTENT_VERSIONID_FROM_REST_API'];
```

Then create your contentDocumentLink by

```
ContentDocumentLink cl = new ContentDocumentLink();
cl.ContentDocumentId = cv.ContentDocumentId;
cl.LinkedEntityId = 'YOUR_INSERTED_EMAIL_MESSAGE_ID;
cl.ShareType = 'V';
cl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
insert cl;
```

This is the Pseudo code, but can be implemented in rest:

Src
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm